# Passing a parameter to a Silverlight user control

Tags: c#, silverlight, user-controls, navigation

In a Silverlight User Control's code behind file there is a method, to which I should pass a string parameter. I'm trying the following way but get an error  ***System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException
       Message=The key is not found in the dictionary.***

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string strid = HtmlPage.Document.QueryString["id"]; // this way it doesn't work
        ReadAndUpdate(strid);
    }

    private void ReadAndUpdate(string shid)
    {
          //some stuff here
    }
 ..........
```

and I call this page like the following:

```
        string idstr = xxxx; // my value
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new
                    System.Uri("/MyPage?id=" + idstr, System.UriKind.Relative));
```

And the above Uri string is appeared in browser as intended (if I'm not trying to parse it in my UserControls' initialization).

MyUserControl is called in the MyPage XAML (where I navigate to):

```
<uc:MyUserControl />
```

**What am I doing wrong? Am I moving in the right direction at all?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about using initParams ? http://www.dotnetspider.com/Silverlight-Tutorial-313.aspx